# The sum of all squares between 1 and 100 inclusive?

Tags: java

Doing an assignment for my computer science class and can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have to write a program that adds all the squares between 1 and 100 (1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100) As part of the assignment I'm required to use a "while" statement, so no "for" statements will help. My current code is as follows.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class While42B {
    public static void main(String []args ) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = 1;
        int sum = 0;
        while (n <= 100) {
            n = (n*n);
            n++;

            sum = (sum + n); 
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

And the return I get from the GUI is

710

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it in your way I mean first square the value of each number,keep it in a variable  and add it to the sum you can use a `different variable` instead of `n` to store the square value of each number like this :

```
int n = 1;
int squareValue;
int sum = 0;
while (n <= 10) {

    squareValue= (n*n);

    sum += squareValue; 

    n++;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Ah fixed it, I also had to limit n to 10, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

Look at this statement:

```
n = (n*n);
```

You're squaring `n` inside the loop, and then incrementing it. Do the following instead:

```
while (n <= 10) {
    sum = (sum + (n*n)); 
    n++;
}
```

This way, you don't modify `n` by squaring it, and you can properly track its value for the while loop.

Comment: This was a really fast response, impressive.

Comment: Thanks, it was fairly quick, though to be honest I'm not a fan of FGITW answers.

Comment: @mellamokb The edit you tried to make is not correct, as it would add up `1,4,9,...,99^2, 10000`

Comment: @hexafraction: Whoops I misread the question.  Sorry about that. Looks good now :)

Comment: I just got 338350 as an output from that, it keeps looping the sum.

Comment: @nickmcneely7 What do you mean by "looping the sum"?

Comment: @hexafraction it doesn't stop once the n value reaches 100 so the sum just keeps getting bigger and bigger until I close the GUI

Comment: @newtonrd like the output? Sorry I'm new to coding and all the terminology involved

Comment: @nickmcneely7 if you are using the code hexafraction has suggested then the loop should always exit. You have said you are using GUI. Do you mean that as in the console? Or have you written some other GUI components (JavaSwing) that are displaying this loop?

Comment: @newtonrd well I'm not sure what my n and sum values should be set to, because I believe that's whats messing up hexafraction 's code for me

Answer (score 9):

I realize you're looking for a while loop but
just FYI you can use the direct formula:

`System.out.println( n * (n + 1) * (2 * n + 1) / 6);`

Comment: Still +1 for a different answer.

Comment: This formula gives a sum of squares between 1 and n^2 inclusive, not between 1 and n.

Answer (score 5):

Just as an add-on, in Java 8, one can do the sum of squares of first 10 natural numbers as follows:

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).map(n -> n * n).sum();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the value of n in: n= n*n
So now you are not looping from 1 to 100, you are skipping a lot of numbers

Answer (score -1):

Simply read the mathematics and then proceed to translate the mathematical operations into code.
I've worked out the mathematics which I hope could help you. I have also provided an answer to the question stated by your professor, I do hope that I am able to have been helpful in your arrangements. No credit needed except to Carl Friedrich Gauss.

X(nsquared base 1 + nsquared base n) divided by 2

X equals number of numbers (100) and n base 1 equals first number (1) and n base n equals last number (100), I did not include the squares in the numerical description but you do need too include squares in the first and last number. 1 squared and 100 squared.

- Do these operations according too PEMDAS ( order of operations ).
- I don't have a high enough reputation so I can't post photos, sorry for that, I hope this all helped though.
- The answer is (500,050)